# JMeter - How to extract query string and request headers?

Tags: regex, jmeter, csrf-token

I am working on log-in scenario for Jmeter. Once I logged-in, I am redirected  to the below request:

https://analogb2c.b2clogin.com/analogb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_ADI_SignUpOrSignInWithKmsi/SelfAsserted?tx=StateProperties=eyJUSUQiOiJlOWRiNTU1Zi05N2ZmLTRmOTYtOGQwMC0yOTc2MGNlYmE4ZDYifQ&p=B2C_1A_ADI_SignUpOrSignInWithKmsi

How do I extract the Query String Parameters "tx" and "p" and "X-CSRF-TOKEN" that is in the request headers? What is the regular expression to get the values? I will use the value to the next succeding request. Thanks

[Query String Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQBNb.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the `tx` it would be something like:

```
tx=(.+?)&
```

[image]

For the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` it would be something like:

```
X-CSRF-TOKEN:\s*(.*)
```

[image]

If you have problems with [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) - you can consider switching to the [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), it basically extracts everything between left and right boundaries, doesn't require any domain knowledge and works much faster. More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)